# Type 'string | string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: typescript

Создал интерфейс:

```
interface SearchData {
   user_ip : string
}
```

И далее заполняю его данными:

```
var config : SearchData = {
    user_ip: req.headers['x-forwarded-for']
}
```

Но это вызывает ошибку

> Type 'string | string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
>     Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Поскольку заголовок `x-forwarded-for` может содержать не один, а несколько IP-адресов. Переписал это так:

```
var config : SearchData = {
    user_ip: req.headers['x-forwarded-for'].hasOwnProperty('length') ? req.headers['x-forwarded-for'][0] : req.headers['x-forwarded-for'],
}
```

Но ошибка не пропала. Как правильно задать значение, чтобы компилятор TypeScript понимал, что в итоге всё равно в свойство задаётся строка?

Comment: поскольку `x-forwarder-for` это неизвестный ключ для `IncomingHttpHeaders`, все последующие значения неизвестных ключей имеют тип `string | string[] | undefined` и если вы уверены что там просто строка почему бы не написать `req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] as string`?

Answer (score 0):

```
Array.isArray(req.headers['x-forwarded-for']) ? req.headers['x-forwarded-for'][0] : req.headers['x-forwarded-for'];
```

Comment: Не сработало...

Answer (score 0):

Можно так:

```
(String)((typeof req.headers["x-forwarded-for"] == "string") ? req.headers["x-forwarded-for"] : req.headers["x-forwarded-for"][0])
```

Вообще вот великолепное чтиво об проверке типов:

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/typeGuard.html

Answer (score -1):

`req.headers.get('x-forwarded-for')`

https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpHeaders
`get()` - Returns the first header value that matches a given name.